# Choosing NOsql or RDMS, and which DataStructure?

Tags: sql, opengl, data-structures, nosql, rdbms

I'm going to start a big 3d modelization project, and i need to choose a system to store my data. The 3d-model in its raw format, before my engine process it, is made of billions of colored triangles.
Inputs :
- Each 3d-model will consist of a very large number of triangles ( 3 space points (bigint x,y,z ), and a color (rgb) ).
- If the INSERT is slow it's not a big deal, but the SELECT must be as fast as possible ( SELECT with some linear WHERE conditions ).
- Data consistancy is not important, if i lost a triangle or two in a model that's not very problematic.
- i can make a table per object, so i can make it read-only and i can put some column indexes (RDMS) on it.

there are my questions :
Data structure :
Many triangles will share the same dots. Should i save the triangles in one table like id x1,y1,z1 x2,y2,z2 x3,y3,z3 ,r,g,b ; or a table for dots id,x,y,z and a table for triangles id,dot1Id,dot2Id,dot3Id,r,g,b  ( a join on billion rows will be slow i think, and with NOsql we can't even do a join if my memory is good... )   ???

RDMS or NOsql ?
I think NOsql is good for what i need, does it do fast conditionnal Selects on very large data ? RDMS can be good too because my data is very formatted and consists of integers, indexes can do magic here.

Answer (score 0):

Being no expert, I cannot really answer your question. But the comments are to short to give you proper advice there. So here are my "comments" in the "answer section" :-)

I understand the model such that it consists of a list (or a set to be precise) of triangles. You will always have to read the complete data to load your model. You don't only load the trianles where x < 100 and y > 1000 or whatever.

So your thoughts to the problem are good. What links your triangles are the points they share. So yes, you could use an RDBMS and store points in one table and their associated triangles in another. However the "pointers" (in your triangle table pointing to your point records) in an RDBMS are usually quite large (the so called row ids), so you don't really save space, but have the need to re-construct all your triangles from their related points, which takes time. My advice: No RDBMS.

If above assumption is right and your model consists of a mere set of triangles in random order, you can easily store them in a file. In some custom binary format, so the file will be rather small. You could even compress it to use less hard disk sectors. No use to store some relation anywhere, just one file per model. You read from beginning to end. It cannot be faster.

I don't know of any NoSQL database being specialized on just storing large binary files. Its only task would be to give you the raw data for a model. I mean it would only save you the trouble to think of a way to store several model files and find them again (and it might do the compression if appropriate). But well, storing the model names with the file names can be done in registry, config file, small text file, whatever. No big deal, I think. So my second advice would be not to use a NoSQL DBMS either. But as mentioned, I'm no exprt on this, and there may be dbms specialized on exactly this (small) task.

Comment: My 3D models will be for a big environnement like houses, hotels ... So often i'll load just some of the triangles of my model ( an appartment room for ex ), this is why i need to filter the data which could be done faster using a DMS. And sometimes my server will receive data to update the 3d model, then i'll have to make some searchs to find which triangles i'll have to split or merge, it will be a pain to load 500mb file in memory and search each time.

Comment: Ah, okay, so there are more relations. A house, its appartments, the appartment's rooms... Then yes, of course you can use a dbms to store these relations. Sounds like a good idea :-) The set of triangles however can still be stored in binary format (in a table column or a file). At least it seems to me you would gain nothing from having the database know what the triangles' coordinates are. RDBMS is okay for this task. As to NoSQL, I have no idea, having no experience with them. And as to the updates: load the binary data for a room, change it and store the new binary again.

Comment: Sorry i haven't explained in details the structure. my 3d model is huge, a whole house for example, but i don't know the parts which makes a room or a living-room, it's one big model for everything. I talked about rooms, because the end-user will navigate through the model using a webinterface, so my server will not just send the billion triangles to WebGl, it will send just the part which should be visible, so the database needs to know the coordonates, this way i can, with just a linear Conditional Where, select visible triangles to send via the network.

Comment: I would go for RDBMS because i'm used to it. but i don't want it to be the main reason, i don't want to choose it just because i don't know the capabilities of NOSql.